# Extract from a file the lines before and after a certain line that as specific character in a certain column using python

Tags: python, file, text

I am trying to read each line of a text file (each line has values that are separated by one or multiple spaces, but it can also be an empty line), and whenever a line has a particular character in a column (in my case I want "H" in column 2 (column 1 in python), and extract the line before(can be an empty line), the line of interest with "H" and the next line (it can be an empty line).

```
input : (file.txt)
173 H B  120.24    8.76
174 Y B  125.13    8.88
175 E B  121.65    8.77
176 T B  122.94    9.22
177 L H  129.04    9.19
178 A B  117.33    7.62
179 R B  122.34    8.15
180 F H  124.32    8.81
181 E B  125.43    8.78
182 L C  124.83    8.13
183 S C  114.31    8.50
184 E C  120.65    8.36
185 H C  119.53    8.52
186 H C  119.67    8.62



  1 M U    ****    ****
  2 A C  127.24    8.61
  3 H B  116.05    8.41
  4 C B  124.62    9.23

output : (output.txt)

173 H B  120.24    8.76
174 Y B  125.13    8.88

184 E C  120.65    8.36 
185 H C  119.53    8.52 
186 H C  119.67    8.62

185 H C  119.53    8.52
186 H C  119.67    8.62

2 A C  127.24    8.61
3 H B  116.05    8.41
4 C B  124.62    9.23
```

Here is the code that I have but I do not manage to obtain what I want:

```
newopen2 = open('./output.txt', 'w')
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        for x, y in enumerate(line):
            if (y[1]) == "H" in line:
               newopen2.write("".join(line[max(0, str(line) - 1):str(line) + 2]).replace('\r', ''))
               newopen2.write("\n")
            else:
               continue
newopen2.close()
f.close()
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Teez

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates a binary array where a 1 indicates the line is to be written to the file.

```py
from typing import List

def propagate_ones(in_array: List) -> List:
    '''Returns a binary sequence which changes an in_array element to a 1
    if it is a 0 and neighbours a 1'''
    propagated_array = in_array.copy()
    for i in range(len(in_array)-1):
        if in_array[i+1] == 1:
            propagated_array[i] = 1
        if in_array[i] == 1:
            propagated_array[i+1] = 1
    return propagated_array

with open('./file.txt', 'r') as fin, open('./out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    in_lines = fin.readlines()
    h_flags = [1 if i != '\n' and i.split()[1]=='H' else 0 for i in in_lines]
    to_write_flags = propagate_ones(h_flags)
    to_write = zip(to_write_flags, in_lines)
    for line in to_write:
        if line[0] == 1:
            fout.write(line[1])
```

This writes the desired output to out.txt:

```
173 H B  120.24    8.76
174 Y B  125.13    8.88
184 E C  120.65    8.36
185 H C  119.53    8.52
186 H C  119.67    8.62

  2 A C  127.24    8.61
  3 H B  116.05    8.41
  4 C B  124.62    9.23
```